# JSON: Extracting Data Using Alamofire and Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift4

Can anyone tell me how to get the data out of this JSON?

Here is my code followed by the JSON

```
let URL = "URL"
Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON
{ response in
print("HereBegins: = \(response)")
let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any]

}
```

the json being returned is...

HereBegins: = SUCCESS: 
{
items =
 (

{

addToCartUrl = "blah blah URL";

affiliateAddToCartUrl = "blah blah another URL";

availableOnline = 0;

brandName = Generic;

bundle = 0;

categoryNode = "976759_1071964_976788";

categoryPath = "Food/Fresh Food/Dairy, Eggs & Cheese/Milk & Cream";

clearance = 0;

customerRating = "5.0";

customerRatingImage = "http://i2.walmartimages.com/i/CustRating/5.gif";

freeShipToStore = 0;

freeShippingOver50Dollars = 1;

giftOptions =             {

allowGiftMessage = 0;

allowGiftReceipt = 0;

allowGiftWrap = 0;

};

imageEntities =

(

{

entityType = SECONDARY;

largeImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/c2bc3886-fb4f-4c46-b7e9-0cc4ebabc7c1_1.d42acf75b29b132532d5953b139b115f.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF";

mediumImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/c2bc3886-fb4f-4c46-b7e9-0cc4ebabc7c1_1.d42acf75b29b132532d5953b139b115f.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF";

thumbnailImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/c2bc3886-fb4f-4c46-b7e9-0cc4ebabc7c1_1.d42acf75b29b132532d5953b139b115f.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF";

},

{

entityType = PRIMARY;

largeImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1d575fe6-b8c9-4dc6-821b-42cbde621373_1.4764431b7ebfb4707c0a2f7fe47e85cc.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF";

mediumImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1d575fe6-b8c9-4dc6-821b-42cbde621373_1.4764431b7ebfb4707c0a2f7fe47e85cc.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF";

thumbnailImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1d575fe6-b8c9-4dc6-821b-42cbde621373_1.4764431b7ebfb4707c0a2f7fe47e85cc.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF";

}

);

isTwoDayShippingEligible = 0;

itemId = 46491746;

largeImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1d575fe6-b8c9-4dc6-821b-42cbde621373_1.4764431b7ebfb4707c0a2f7fe47e85cc.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF";

longDescription = "<br><b>Great Value Vanilla Almond Milk, 64 fl oz:</b><br><ul><li>Delicious flavor</li><li>Great Value almond milk comes in a 64 fl oz carton</li><li>Vitamins A, D and E added</li><li>Added calcium</li><li>Only 80 calories per serving</li></ul>";

marketplace = 0;

mediumImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1d575fe6-b8c9-4dc6-821b-42cbde621373_1.4764431b7ebfb4707c0a2f7fe47e85cc.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF";

modelNumber = 11951;

name = "Great Value Vanilla Almond Milk, 64 fl oz";

ninetySevenCentShipping = 0;

numReviews = 3;

offerType = "STORE_ONLY";

parentItemId = 46491746;

preOrder = 0;

productTrackingUrl = "http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.walmart.com%252Fip%252FGreat-Value-Vanilla-Almond-Milk-64-fl-oz%252F46491746%253Faffp1%253DHzNQqMKL6fuAwFZnu_RUqysY3U3RzuxH0bQKAHNYr0Q%2526affilsrc%253Dapi";

productUrl = "http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api03?l=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FGreat-Value-Vanilla-Almond-Milk-64-fl-oz%2F46491746%3Faffp1%3DHzNQqMKL6fuAwFZnu_RUqysY3U3RzuxH0bQKAHNYr0Q%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlyapi";

salePrice = "2.58";

shipToStore = 0;

standardShipRate = 0;

stock = "Not available";

thumbnailImage = "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1d575fe6-b8c9-4dc6-821b-42cbde621373_1.4764431b7ebfb4707c0a2f7fe47e85cc.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF";

upc = 078742052366;

}

);

}

Comment: Why did this get down voted?? Would it have been better to explain the obvious and say... "I've looked everywhere and other peoples solutions aren't working for me! Someone please help." For some reason I am not being able to access anything from this JSON. when I print 'result' I can get something and I can't even do a result!["items"] but I can go any further than that.

Comment: I didn't down vote but the JSON – which is not JSON by the way – is a horrible mess. You are encouraged to format your code properly.

Comment: thanks for info. I got the JSON or whatever it is from Walmart actually haha and they call it JSON so I have no idea what it is then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
                    if let resData = result["items"].arrayObject {
                        arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                        for element in arrRes[0]
                        {
                            print(element)
                        }
                        print(arrRes[0]["name"])
```